# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Tags: android

I'm having this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

here is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ankit.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

    compile files('libs/volley.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiDexEnabled true in your defaultConfig
defaultConfig {
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

OR
[Gradle Build failed with an exception : java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366866/gradle-build-failed-with-an-exception-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-va)