# keep getting error Gradle Build failed with an exception : java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 2 after adding library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I keep getting below error when i add new library into gradle:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.whc.news"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}


dependencies {


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(":volley")
    compile project(":AndroidBootstrap")
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    provided 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366866/gradle-build-failed-with-an-exception-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-va), There's written that a conflict is the reason of this error.  I do not know what is the conflict in my `gradle` dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - What is a non-zero exit value and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle/30692005#30692005

Comment: Use gradlew assemble --info to get more details about the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to compile this as whole as it is, Most of the time this causes over 65K methods dex limit.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

[see here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project), Find out the specific one that you really need And use those as per your need for the specific purposes, and it seems you also forgot to add `multiDexEnabled true`.

Comment: i change `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'` and it worked! thank alot

Answer (score 0):

Include this line inside your `defaultConfig`:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.whc.news"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

For more info see [Building Apps with Over 64K Methods](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)

See this [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle/30692005#30692005)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That is not the only step in enabling multidex and that is not always a recommended solution to the problem

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi yes